# Remove unwanted material

Tags: modeling

So guys here is the problem. I add a material to a mesh, then I feel like I don't want that. How can I delete it? Even when I am deleting it, it's still there after reopening in the drop down list of materials. Now the thing is it says that it has 3 users although i can't see any. Please do help me I am attaching the file as well.

Link to file : https://gofile.io/?c=VltNPo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**To find all the objects currently using a material.**

- If you have one of the objects selected,  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (*Select Linked*) > *Material* will select all visible objects using the same material as the one in the active slot. ( you may have to unhide objects to select them).
- If you can't easily track down the object, you can switch the Outliner to Data API view (highlighted)..

[image]

.. select the material you're interested in, right-click, and, again, *Select Linked*.

**To unlink a material from all objects** ..
(Setting users to 0, even if you haven't found them)

- Shift-click the 'Unlink' button in the materials panel ..

..Although it will continue to appear in the dropdown, the material will not be saved in the .blend file. Next time you open the file, the material will be gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 2.77a but it shouldn't be that much different in later versions.

To delete unused materials, expand the Outliner's menu and select "Orphaned Data".  That will list redundant items.  With the mouse cursor on the Outliner Panel header strip, scroll the wheel until you see "Purge All" button.  Pressing this repeatedly deletes the items shown and leaving just 'Brushes'.  Leave that one alone.

When you return to the Outliner's Menu and reselect 'Scene' or Visible Layers', those deleted items will be gone.  (Press the right arrow on the keyboard to update the display)

As for materials showing a number in the 'Users' slot, check the materials list and if that material is showing a "0" at it's left, it's likely the users slot showing a number is the result of Blender not updating that for some reason.

[image]

On past occasions when I've encountered this I've gone back to the Users number and clicked on it. It then goes back to Fake user 'F' or nothing, reinforcing the view that it hadn't updated earlier.